# Quote expected on column 399

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have the below string in my jsp but when I run the program, I get an error from tomcat that quote expected on column 399:

```
<script>
var string = "<td class=\"tabletextcont\"><a cssClass=\"deleteLinks\" onclick=\"showConfirmationBox(\"<app:root nolang='true'/>/c2/app/Delete.action?param1=" + 
param1+ "&param2=" + param2+ "&param3=" + param3 + "&param4=" + param4+ "&param5=" + param5 + "&param6="+param6");return false;\"><img alt='<s:text name=\"command.delete\"/>' border=\"none\" src=\"<s:url value=\"/images/delete2.gif\"/>\"/></a></td>";
</script>
```

All the param1-6 are values that are received from struts 2 `<s:property />` tag, at the moment, all of them are either null or empty.

I don't understand where the problem is, I have tried various combinations of quotes with any luck.

Comment: how can you directly used `jsp` variable in `javascript`?

Comment: You have some serious nesting going on there. Combined with the requirements for escaping that is going to get "interesting". I suggest you start with something simple and then add to it in stages until you get to the end result you want.